# Install Android Studio on Linux Mint 18.1 - Permission Denied

Tags: android-studio, installation, linux-mint

Trying to install Android Studio 2.3.0.8 for Linux on Linux Mint 18.1 (64bit) however it isn't working.

I have downloaded the zip; **android-studio-ide-162.3764568-linux.zip** -from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html and followed the instructions in the user guide and other stackoverflow questions but it won't install.

The steps I take are:

(1) Extract **android-studio-ide-162.3764568-linux.zip** to /home/username/Downloads. I have also tried moving the folder (using terminal command **sudo mv from/file /usr/local** and to /opt/). However the result is always the same

(2) Run in terminal; **cd ./Downloads/android-studio/bin** or /usr/local, etc. then enter the command **./studio.sh**

I have tried tried this a number of times but it still wont work. ;

> "username@username-MS-7970 ~/Downloads/android-studio/bin $ ./studio.sh
>
> bash: ./studio.sh: Permission denied"

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
  sezpanda@sezpanda-MS-7970 /opt/android-studio/bin $ sudo ls -a
  [sudo] password for sezpanda: 
  .                    idea.properties   log.xml             studio.vmoptions
  ..                   inspect.sh        os                  subprocess
  appletviewer.policy  libbreakgen64.so  studio64.vmoptions  sys
  fsnotifier           libbreakgen.so    studio.png
  fsnotifier64         lldb              studio.sh
  sezpanda@sezpanda-MS-7970 /opt/android-studio/bin $
```

Comment: Does `sudo ./studio.sh` work?

Comment: No. Then the terminal thinks "./studio.sh" is a command and states 'command not found'

Comment: Are you in the directory with `studio.sh`? If you are it shouldn't say command not found

Comment: I definitely am
'~/Downloads/android-studio/bin $ sudo ./studio.sh

[sudo] password for sezpanda: 

sudo: ./studio.sh: command not found'. I opened the terminal from that folder to be sure

Comment: Can you edit the output of `ls -a` into the question?

Comment: Yeah i checked it is definitely the right folder before i execute the command but it still says command not found.

Comment: `studio.sh` should be executable by default(it was for me at least) you might try `chmod +x ./studio.sh` then `./studio.sh`

Comment: sezpanda@sezpanda-MS-7970 /opt/android-studio/bin $ chmod +x ./studio.sh
chmod: changing permissions of './studio.sh': Operation not permitted

Comment: This says you are in `opt/android-studio/bin` and your last response said you were in `~/Downloads/android-studio/bin` ensure you are in the proper directory and execute `./studio.sh` it will be executable by default.

Comment: yeah i have tried both, and actually have the files saved in both locations just to be sure

Answer (score 1):

Simply download .zip from official url i.e. [android_studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/) & then check whether there is java installed or not on your system, to check simply do,

```
java -version
```

will return something like this,

```
openjdk version "11.0.3" 2019-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.3+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.3+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Then extract .zip & go to extracted zip folder & then go to bin, open your Terminal & perform these two step & Android Studio will get successfully installed on your system,

```
sudo chmod +x ./studio.sh

sudo ./studio.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

You might not have chmod +x studio.sh try sh ./studio.sh

If this was not it, try again like this: sh -x ./studio.sh. This will show you every line that is run and will help you debug it.

Good luck.

Comment: sh ./studio.sh works but only as a temporary load, and most of the repositories/plugins are missing and the sdkmanager doesn't install either so I can't compile or test anything

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo chmod +x ./studio.sh
sudo sh ./studio.sh
```